# Gtk Warning Theme parsing error, trying to do some facial recognition

Tags: python, gtk

i'm having what i think is a gtk error in python while trying to recognize some faces and then apply a gaussian blur, i'm new in python! Here is the error:

*Gtk-WARNING **: 00:11:03.559: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6321:10: "height" is not a valid property name*

i'm currently using Archlinux and python 3+, i checked ~/.config and my Gtk is 2.0, idk if that is the issue and i also don't know how to change it/ update it.

Here is the code i'm triying to compile:

```
from skimage.filters import gaussian
from skimage import color
from skimage import data

import scipy.misc
import os
import sys
import plots
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
path = "/home/carlos/python/img/jaja.jpeg"
img = plt.imread("/home/carlos/python/img/girl.jpeg")
#plt.show(img)
trained_file = data.lbp_frontal_face_cascade_filename()

detector = Cascade(trained_file)

detected = detector.detect_multi_scale(img=img, scale_factor=1.2, step_ratio=1, min_size=(50,50), max_size=(200,200))

print(detected)
```

Comment: Are you running a custom theme on your system?

Comment: I'm not sure haha, like i said i'm using arch linux but i'm also using a windows manager environment (qtile,python based i think) i'm not pretty sure if that (qtile) counts as a theme, besides qtile, i have some fonts and i think that's all i have